# Ruby dynamic "typecasting" using class names stored in a variable

Tags: ruby

I'd like to setup a hash like so:

```
{:a => Float, :b => String}
```

so that I can use it as a "typecast" filter against another hash. For example:

```
def parse_hash(input_hash)
  output = { :a => Float, :b => String }
  input_hash.each do |k,v|
    input_hash[k] = output[k](v)
  end
end
```

The idea is, you can do:

```
Float("123") #=> 123.0
```

but unfortunately, you can't do:

```
f = Float
f("123") #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `f' for main:Object
```

...which means the hash parse method I'm going for doesn't work.

So, if I have a reference to a class in a variable, is there any way to get from there to automatically coercing a value to that class?

Comment: This should work: `Kernel.send f.name, "123"`

Comment: Brilliant! You should make this an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: I don't understand your error message regarding `f = Float; f("123")`. Where does `v` come from?

Comment: @sawa My bad, that was a typo, should have been "f". Corrected now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a subtle difference between `Float` which is a class and `Float` which is a method. The Ruby interpreter will differentiate on the syntax level, it's based on how you use it. `Float("1.0")` is a trigger for the method, as is `Float "1.0"`, but `a = Float` is interpreted as the class.

You need to capture the method specifically:

```
output = {
  a: method(:Float),
  b: method(:String)
}
```

Then later, to call it:

```
output[:a].call('1.7')
# => 1.7
```

Comment: Woow!! The one I was searching since 2 days back.. But this one doesn't appear in my mind.. :) Thanks..

Comment: Or with an explicit receiver: `Kernel.method(:Float)`

Comment: Alternatively: `output = {a: :to_f, b: :to_s}` and call with `x.send(output[:a])` if you prefer NoMethodErrors to TypeErrors.

Comment: Although I am having another confusion between [`Kernel#Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-Hash) and [`Hash#Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) .. Any light on this? How ruby interpreter choose which one to use...?

Comment: The second one is `Hash.[]` method. So it is called when you write `Hash[bla bla]`, the first one is called when you write `Hash()` (check the parens).

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier Thank you to you also..You made my day!! :)

Comment: This is really interesting. I could tell that this distinction (method vs class) is what was going on, but I wasn't sure how to capture the method, or if it was "capturable". I actually tried calling `methods.include?(:Float)` when I was testing this, but I didn't think to call it directly on Kernel and it returned false... not sure why MainObject wouldn't respond true to that...

Answer (score 1):

As a build on tadman's answer, here are all the Kernel methods that are the exception to the convention that method names are not capitalized:

```
2.0.0p247 :021 > Kernel.methods.grep /(^[A-Z][a-z]+)+$/
 => [:Integer, :Float, :String, :Array, :Hash, :Rational, :Complex]
```

Update: Modified search to accommodate camel case while still avoiding all-caps. Excludes methods with any non-alpha characters in the name, for better or worse. Note also that frameworks may add to this list. Nod to Stefan on both counts.

Comment: Plus `BigDecimal` and `Pathname` if you require that modules. You can simplify your lookup: `Kernel.methods.grep /^[A-Z]/`

Answer (score 0):

Your confusion between the classes `Float`, `String` and the methods `Float`, `String` is one issue as pointed out by tadman, but another issue with your code is that

```
v = ...
```

within the hash loop is not doing anything to the hash. If you wanted to change the value of the hash, you have to do:

```
input_hash[k] = ...
```

Comment: Oh good point. I'm actually using this is a larger chunk of metaprogramming and I typed up the "abridged" example code above to try and focus on just the part that wasn't working rather than paste the whole code. I've updated the question to clear up that problem for future people who find this. Thanks!